# Group objects by same value keys

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object called results. In this object I have data about test history. So I have multiple objects with the same ID but status or date_created can be different. Like this.

```
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "row_id": "G_6",
        "status": "PASS",
        "date_created": "2023-07-11T07:43:23.807962",
        "date_last_updated": "2023-07-11T07:43:23.807962"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "row_id": "G_6",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "date_created": "2023-08-01T12:05:40.973614",
        "date_last_updated": "2023-08-01T12:05:40.973614"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "row_id": "G_6",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "date_created": "2023-09-01T12:05:40.973614",
        "date_last_updated": "2023-09-01T12:05:40.973614"
      }, 
      {
        "id": 1,
        "row_id": "G_7",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "date_created": "2023-10-01T12:05:40.973614",
        "date_last_updated": "2023-10-01T12:05:40.973614"
      }, 
    ]
```

what I want to achieve is to have One main object for each row_ID and for this object to have children or history that are the rest of the results with the same ID. Of course order should be descending so the youngest object is a parent and the second youngest is a child etc...

so it should look like this

```
"results": [
  {
    {
      "id": 1,
      "row_id": "G_6",
      "status": "FAILED",
      "date_created": "2023-09-01T12:05:40.973614",
      "date_last_updated": "2023-09-01T12:05:40.973614",
      "history": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "row_id": "G_6",
          "status": "FAILED",
          "date_created": "2023-08-01T12:05:40.973614",
          "date_last_updated": "2023-08-01T12:05:40.973614"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "row_id": "G_6",
          "status": "PASS",
          "date_created": "2023-07-11T07:43:23.807962",
          "date_last_updated": "2023-07-11T07:43:23.807962"
        },
      ]
    }, {
    "id": 1,
    "row_id": "G_7",
    "status": "FAILED",
    "date_created": "2023-10-01T12:05:40.973614",
    "date_last_updated": "2023-10-01T12:05:40.973614",
    "history":[]
}}]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+group+objecct+by+id+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.